# How can i create a filtered table based on the value of this card which is linked to a slicer

Tags: powerbi

In my dashboard I have a table that contains the following columns: Tickers, Sector, PE and Market Cap. I want to create a dax formula that will create a new table which is filtered based on the sector which results from my chosen ticker, See screenshot
[Visual of my dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/We7Si.png)

How can I achieve this or something close to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this type of thing you need to have an auxiliary table in your model for plotting. This is correct! But you don't need to recalculate this table based on your selection.

Let's say you have a table like this in the model already:

| Company | Sector | PE | Mkt Cap | Country | ... | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Data | 5 | 10 | USA |  |  |
| B | Data | 10 | 200 | China |  |  |
| C | Not Data | 12 | 30 | Japan |  |  |

You will need to persist a new table in your model with the data you need. For the above, simple example, this can be a simple `SUMMARIZE`, but for your real data it might require some sort of aggregation for `PE` and `Mkt Cap`:

```
Plotting = 
SUMMARIZE ( 
    'Table' , 
    'Table'[Company] , 
    'Table'[Sector] , 
    'Table'[PE] , 
    'Table'[Mkt Cap]
)
```

This table you will connect to your original table using a **single direction** many-many relationship between `Sector` columns, where the **original table filters `Plotting`**:

[image]

You can now use the columns from `Plotting` in your visual to show the PE/MktCap information for companies in the same selected sector:

[image]

Inevitably, this example solution will differ from your actual solution since my example table isn't exactly the same as your table, but this is the general technique you need to apply for this plotting use-case.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. Calculated columns and calculated tables are static and recalculate upon refresh only, but not on slicer changes.